How to make a field that slows all motion within?
I have some sort of device that can slow down all motion within a little localized field around it, and the main purpose of doing this is to slow down aging by literally slowing/damping the kinetic energy and motion of the bodily processes, with the overall visible effect also being that the user’s movement and reactions are slowed down too.
Basically functioning like how a time-slowing field would work, except there’s no aspect of relativity to it where it only seems like the user’s lifespan has been expanded to outside observers; it’s almost more like a literal real-life slow-mo device.
What’s the most plausible explanation, based on some sort of real-world tech model or theoretical physics design or something along those lines, for this function? Note that the device should be portable, so preferably not like a stasis chamber requiring a shell with huge amounts of gravity/energy inside stable walls, but rather something that could essentially follow the user around.

The usual word for such a device is a refrigerator. Slowing down the motion of molecules is literally what a refrigerator does. The "overall visible effect" is that the objects placed in a refrigerator become cold, which does indeed result in biological processes being slowed down. (The potentially undesirable effect is that humans will die if their internal temperature drops below 35.0 °C (95.0 °F).)

You’re not trying to slow motion, you’re trying to slow time. As far as we know, the only thing that meaningfully does that is moving at relativistic speeds or huge gravitational fields. There’s nothing in modern science that suggests the possibility of a human portable time dilation device.

Just call it a chroniton field and call it a day. You truly don’t need a scientific explanation.

Depending on what "all motion" covers, this could have some nasty complications. If breathing or the movement of blood through the body slows down enough, then it could straight up suffocate people - because the ability to take in oxygen would be slowed but the consumption of oxygen in chemical processes would still be happening in real time.

Hello @Wificare. You seem to believe that there's science behind what you want to achieve and you just need to find the right person to explain it to you. I'm afraid that's not the case. Consider reading Advice: real facts vs. worldbuilding rules. Unless you're willing to consider a sphere that universally increases gravity (the only test we empirically know will slow the experience of time) you're stuck. It's often impossible to make fiction factual.

Please note these two questions also: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/197817/slowing-time-slows-gravity/197820#197820 and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/200609/small-space-of-slow-down-time/200622#200622

Maybe it doesn't slow time, but slows watches - that may be doable with actual science/technology.

@Escapeddentalpatient.: My mechanical watch is slow by nature, losing about 30 seconds per day; there's no need for any fancy technology to make a slow watch. And I have it on good authority that any watch will eventually slow down to zero.

@Escapeddentalpatient. slowing down a watch would mean things move "faster", not slower, if measured. If something travels x length in 1 second (normal watch), then you slow the watch by half, that would mean the same object travels 2 * x for 1 second according to the slowed down watch. Even if we asumed the field speeds up watches, therefore, making measurements seems as if movement slowed, watchers would not be affected. An observer should be able to tell the speed is the same.

Oh, you're measuring time by something other than a watch then. That's fine. Limbs are harder to slow down. Treacle maybe? @VLAZ Only science-based answer that comes to mind here without applying some kind of neurotoxin. (Or fooling the observers into thinking they've been changed too)

If I look with my eyes at something moving (outside the field), then later see it moving again (inside the field), I'd be able to tell that it doesn't move at twice the speed or half the speed compared to before. I might not be able to tell the exact difference for, say, 5-10% speed change, though. I might still pick up that it's "faster" or "slower". Other people might even be more observant. But me and other people can generally count fairly accurate seconds. Well, at least for changing speed by a factor of two, we'd be able to go "One... two... wait, it didn't take <one/four> seconds?!"

Also, assuming we only see an object move within the field, it'd still be a hard sell to make it seem it's moving at half the speed. If you drop the object, it'd be fairly evident when it doesn't fall within the expected velocity. Say, I dropped an egg from ~1.5 meters (just lift my hand to torso level) and my watch told me it took five seconds to reach the ground, then I'd immediately believe my watch is misbehaving. Heck, I even regularly see these. Especially nowadays with various computing devices. It's often that a watch freezes for a moment and then "jumps" ahead by, say, 30 seconds.

"Basically functioning like how a time-slowing field would work, except there’s no aspect of relativity to it where it only seems like the user’s lifespan has been expanded to outside observers; it’s almost more like a literal real-life slow-mo device."
this clashes with the statement that bodily processes are also slowed down. Neuron activation is also a bodily process. Slowing that down would also slow the perception of anyone in the field. The result would be that for anyone inside the field everything in the field happens at normal speed and the outside is accelerated.

If you reduce the kinetic energy of molecules, bio processes eventually just stop completely. Given that “biological processes stopping completely” is usually take to be synonymous with “death”, you don’t want your field to be doing that under the hood. If you want to mess with time, mess with time, not biochemistry.
The most plausible scenario is, of course, relativity. I imagine a metric
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=c^2 \mathrm{d}\tau^2=\left(\frac{1-\tanh(\sigma(r-R))}{2k}\right)c^2 \mathrm{d}t^2-\mathrm{d} x^2-\mathrm{d} y^2-\mathrm{d} z^2$$
which produces a localized region (a sphere centered on the origin of the coordinate system with radius $R$ and boundary “tightness” $\sigma$) where time moves more slowly by a factor of $k$ (in the limit of large $\sigma$). I have not calculated the stress-energy tensor associated with this metric by the Einstein field equations, but I expect that when I check it later it will have very large values.
Unfortunately, this will never be portable. I have done a lot of research on low-energy gravity manipulation and I’ll just say that it’s hard to find a solution that doesn’t require asteroids or moons compressed into tiny boxes moving at near-lightspeed to work.
I can’t think of a better solution.

On the other hand, why are you trying to explain this?
A very common question on this site is “I have this really cool device, how do I explain how it works?” and my answer is often “don’t try” (if in comments, not answers). You do not need to explain absolutely everything in your stories scientifically; I as a reader am often quite bored when the author tries (and inevitably fails). If this device is important to your plot, and you can’t think of a decent explanation, and if having an explanation isn’t equally critical to the plot, then just handwave it.
Often works like Interstellar are praised for being scientifically accurate and successful at the same time, but simultaneously Star Trek is sometimes considered one of the top sci fi franchises of all time and isn’t even sort of scientifically-based. Handwaving is okay is what that teaches us.

The fact that the movie where love powered time traveling ghosts are a pivotal plot point is treated as hard sci-fi is baffling to me.
